# How do I know to refresh my linq queries?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have a basic grid of Linq2Sql entities (frmList).  I have a separate form for editing (frmEdit).  frmEdit has its own DataContext (as that appears to be the recommended way).  How can I tell when my detail form has saved changes?

I don't see a built-in method.  I am considering raising an event on the detail form when I save the datacontex, but not sure how I consume this event on frmList, and I have a feeling these events are already created for me somewhere?

Thanks - as you can probably tell, I am not fully grokking events yet.

Comment: You don't say what environment these forms are running in: asp.net? winforms? wpf? silverlight? Without that we can't say what is available

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing these are simple windows forms then as you said raise an event like the following:

```
' Declare an event at module level.
Event EditCompleted()
```

raise event after the `db.SubmitChanges()`

```
' Raise the event.
RaiseEvent EditCompleted()
```

Listen to these events:

```
Private WithEvents EditForm as new frmEdit
```

in this same form (frmList):

```
Private Sub OnEditCompleted() Handles EditForm.EditCompleted
   'Refresh your frmList
End Sub
```

Please, correct me if im wrong! :)